# Additional characters in a modal window message

Tags: html

I have a modal window (code below) and there are options for translating the message into languages (code below) depending on the value in the input. But for some reason these messages are displayed with a period at the beginning of the message. How can this be solved? Maybe other scripts on the page are interfering?

```
 if (storagePhone.hasOwnProperty(offer) && storagePhone[offer].includes(phone)) {
          var errorMessage, errorTitle;
          switch (country.toUpperCase()) {
            case 'AL':
              errorTitle = "Gabim";
              errorMessage = "Më vjen keq, keni dërguar tashmë një kërkesë."; 
              break;
            case 'RS':
              errorTitle = "Грешка";
              errorMessage = "Извините, већ сте поднели захтев.";
              break;
```

```
    const modalHTML = `
    <!-- Модальное окно  -->
    <div id="mmyMModal" class="mmodalWWindow">
      <div class="mmodal-ccontent">
        <p id="eerror-ttitle" class="mmodal-ttext"></p>
        <div class="success_icon">
          <p>X</p>
        </div>
        <span class="ccloseWWindow">&times;</span>
        <p id="mmodalTText" class="mmodal-ttext"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  `;
```

[Here is a picture of an example message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4SQ4.png)

I converted the error text by replacing special Unicode characters with corresponding HTML entities. For example, for the characters ë and ç, ë and ç accordingly, but it didn't help

Comment: What `direction` do you have? `rtl`? Watch how there is only one `.`

Comment: @deEr yes, but for some reason the letters are still from right to left, and not vice versa, and the period is placed at the very beginning

Comment: I did a JSFiddle with a short test. I think that is the quirks one has to wrap its head around. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction#setting_right-to-left_direction . Try a simple `#mmyMModal {direction:ltr}`.